# Aspect ratio issues with Iphone X

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, nslayoutconstraint

I developed most of my UI on storyboard by creating constraint setup with aspect ratio. Now I find out that on iphone X all the constraint with ratio looks stretched and incorrect. What is the best solution to set constraint with aspect ratio that best fit across all iphone sizes?

Comment: There's no reason for an element to *"look stretched and incorrect"* when using aspect ratio. Show an example of what you're talking about?

Comment: @DonMag, for example I got a background image set 50% height of the superview(whole screen), above the background image there is another smaller image set to 30% height of the background image. On normal iphone the ratio are ok but when comes to iphone X, the image become stretched because iphone X provide a different ratio compare to others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing "aspect ratio" with "percentage".

If you want your background image to not look "stretched" when the size changes, you need to either give it an aspect ratio + percentage size, or use different images.

For example:

- an iPhone SE screen is `320 x 568` so an image that is 50% of the height (and 100% of the width) will be `320 x 284`.
- an iPhone 8 screen is `375 x 667` so an image that is 50% of the height (and 100% of the width) will be `375 x 333.5`.
- an iPhone X screen is `375 x 812` so an image that is 50% of the height (and 100% of the width) will be `375 x 406`.

Obviously, your image cannot be `320 x 284` ***and*** `375 x 333.5` ***and*** `375 x 406` all at the same time.

Instead of setting your image view to 50% of the height of the screen, you may need to constrain it to the full *width* of the screen and give it an `Aspect Ratio` constraint. It won't cover the same percentage height on each device (don't forget about iPad sizes), but it won't look stretched.

Comment: bro can you give me more example or guide to how to set like what you mean? Because I am too new on swift

Comment: Tough to describe in the abstract. Post your images, and I'll show you the differences.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what others do for this, but what I've done to solve this case is put a `size` (height and width) constraint rather than an `aspect ratio` constraint. This may cause it to be a slightly different size on different screens, but the aspect ratio stays the same.

For example,
Instead of setting `aspect ratio` constraint on a square view, try
setting a constraint on the `height` and `width` to equal values, for instance, `250` and `250`.

Comment: Also, maybe check out this article https://medium.com/@kahseng.lee123/how-to-solve-the-most-common-interface-problems-when-adapting-apps-ui-for-iphone-x-44c0f3c80d84